# SQL Tall Table to Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have an ouptut that looks like

```
ID | Version | Date | Value | Value Type
1  | 1       | 2012 | 1     | x
1  | 1       | 2012 | 1.5   | y
1  | 2       | 2012 | 2.3   | x
1  | 2       | 2012 | 1.7   | y
```

I want the output to look like

```
ID | Version | Date | X   | Y
1  | 1       | 2012 | 1   | 1.5   
1  | 2       | 2012 | 2.3 | 1.7
```

Thanks!

Comment: What relational database are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using SQL Server there are several ways that you can get the result.

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select id, version, date,
  max(case when valuetype = 'X' then value end) X,
  max(case when valuetype = 'Y' then value end) Y
from yourtable
group by id, version, date;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15597/1).

Starting in SQL Server 2005, the PIVOT function was introduced.  If you have a limited number of values, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select id, version, date, X, Y
from
(
  select id, version, date, valuetype, value
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for valuetype in (X, Y)
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15597/2).  Finally if you have an unknown number of values, then you will need to use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(ValueType) 
                    from yourtable
                    group by ValueType
                    order by ValueType
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT id, version, date,' + @cols + N' 
            from 
            (
              select id, version, date, valuetype, value
              from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for valuetype in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15597/3)

Comment: Also, what if there are actually 25 cases? I only put X and Y but in fact there are many more

Comment: @MathLover If you have 25 cases, then you will either have to hard-code the query or use dynamic SQL - see my edit with exampless

Comment: in the pivot portion, can we have something like: "for valutype in tableOFValueNames" ?

Comment: @MathLover Are you saying that the value types are stored in a separate table?  If so, then you can't query a table inside of the pivot `IN` clause.  If you are using dynamic sql, then you would have to create the list of columns by querying that separate table.  You might have to edit your question with the correct requirements if this is not clear.